# Reuse existing space in tablespace files (ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace USERS)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, tablespace

I recently ran into the following Oracle error

```
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace USERS
```

So I extended the `USERS` tablespace with another 5 GByte file.

Unfortunately after some time the error came back and I can see that the newly created file is already full. The `USERS` tablespace is already more than 30 GByte big.

How can I reuse some of the existing space that should be free since I have dropped some users?

Comment: This is really a DBA question - see dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you drop users, which by extension drops all the associated objects, Oracle should be able to automatically use the space that was freed.  It would be a different story if you were trying to free space by deleting rows. In that case, you would have to shrink the space used by the table so that you can reuse the space elsewhere.  But this does not seem to be your case.

Comment: @sstan Yes, after dropping the users Oracle automatically used the free space. If you convert your comment to an answer I can tick it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving comment to an answer)

If you drop users, which by extension drops all the associated objects, Oracle will be able to automatically use the space that was freed.

It would be a different story if you were trying to free space by deleting rows. In that case, you would have to shrink the space used by the table so that you can reuse the space elsewhere. But this is not your case.